# Unable to find an entry point named 'WSManInitialize' in DLL 'WsmSvc.dll'

Tags: c#, powershell, inner-exception

I'm using C# service to execute Powershell commands on a remote machine and show the results.
I'm using C# library System.Management.Automation.Runspaces to executing the commands on remote system.

On one of the server, TypeInitializationException has occured while creating Runspace and the service is crashed.

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://" + server + "/powershell"), strShellUri, cred);
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
```

Even after we capture the exception in try-catch block, the service is crashed. On googling, the exception is triggered by Inner Exception.

> InnerException: System.EntryPointNotFoundException
>   Message=Unable to find an entry point named 'WSManInitialize' in DLL 'WsmSvc.dll'.
>   StackTrace:
>    at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.Client.WSManNativeApi.WSManInitialize(Int32 flags, IntPtr& wsManAPIHandle)
>    at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.Client.WSManClientSessionTransportManager. WSManAPIStaticData..ctor()
>    at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.Client.WSManClientSessionTransportManager ..cctor()

How can i resolve the inner exception issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WsmSvc.dll` (or one of its dependencies) is likely outdated (or an incompatible version)0 on your computer where you try to run your code. The only solution to this is to install / update this dll. (Assuming that the error message is correct.)

You can try using [`Dependency Walker`](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if any dependent dll is missing or to inspect exported functions in `WsmSvc.dll`. Run it on the server where you get the error.

Comment: The Error giving server contains the older version and it doesn't have the method WSManInitialize. I'm updating it to the latest version and check

Comment: After updating to new version, the Exception is not thrown and Service works well.